# Reload particular div when rotates device

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation, reload, screen-rotation

I'm trying to create a function, which auto reload the content in div when rotates the devices (from tablet resolution -> desktop resolution, and reverse). I tried with reload location url. It works, but I want to apply it only for div element, without location reload.

Here is my code:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 1023 && window.innerWidth < 1023 || window.innerHeight < 1023 && window.innerWidth >= 1023) {
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
        //location.reload();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have idea about this? Thank you guys for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery then you can do something like

```
jQuery( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) { ... } )
```

More info

https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Answer (score 0):

If your div had an id of `blockA`, you could do something like

```
    function updateDiv(){ 
    $( "#blockA" ).load(window.location.href + " #blockA" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the data in your div - don't use `location.reload`:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
    div.innerHTML = "Reloaded"; //Reload the div here
});
```